# How to publish OpenStreetMap (OSM) layer on GeoServer directly?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap

Is it possible to directly publish OpenStreetMap (OSM) format data to GeoServer?

Can any one guide me to publish i.e. without loading the OSM data into MySQL or PostgreSQL.

Just publish the OSM format data from the folder where the file is located.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with some more details? As a minimum, add definition of "directly", your server configuration, what you've already researched, what you've tried on the basis of that research, what worked and what didn't (and what happened instead)? This will help us to help you.

Answer (score 2):

This [GeoServer blog posting](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/01/30/geoserver-and-openstreetmap/) says that it is not possible to do this:

> **OpenStreetMap** provides instructions on downloading their data.  The
>   full data set is a large file, currently about 4GB when compressed and
>   about 100GB when uncompressed.  (You can download sections of the data
>   set as well.)  This **data is an XML-based data format that GeoServer
>   cannot read natively**.

The bolding is mine.

Comment: How the world moves on - the compressed version is now over 40Gb!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no

long answer: OSM XML is just an exchange format and not tuned for any direct use like rendering or routing. Therefor you need need formats with more geospatial abilities, most in use is PostGIS.

But if you like to avoid creating a local DB, you might be already lucky with [preprocessed shapefiles](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefile) and you can also create them easiy using QGIS 2.0.