# Does GeoServer support OpenStreetMap OSM format?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, tilestache

Apologies if the question has been asked but I am kind of lost between al the resources and tools available.

I set up a GeoServer and have been reading the documentation but I still don't understand how to serve tiles from OpenStreetMap.

I might have misunderstood the tools to achieve building a simple world map with multiple styles. Using Leaflet and OSM works fine as a demo app and as I understand, I need to have multiple maps generated on my server in order to have custom styled maps. The only layers I want are roads, boundaries, with different colors.

Am I using the wrong tools?
If not, how is GeoServer going to help me serve maps with the following example set of URLs and layers?

Example :

- myserver.com/dark/z/x/y
- myserver.com/blue/z/x/y
- etc

At first I used Mapbox and created multiple maps but their pricing is too high for my small starting business, but it does what I want to achieve. I would like to do it myself and I have a developer background.

Again I'm sorry I'm mixing everything, I'm willing to get more documentation on the matter and I think this could be basic to achieve as I don't want to get deep into customization. Please feel free to redirect me to any tool/documentation in order to host my custom tile server.

Comment: Are you referring to OSM files or OpenStreetMap as a background Map for your data?

Comment: I am refering to OSM files as I would need to custom these. I came across Maptiler Cloud and I think it might to the job very well. I certainly should give up on hosting my own tile server and rendering my maps because I think it's too big of a job, but I still would like to know how I could manage hosting these myself, just for learning purposes.

Comment: Use osm2pgsql for importing OSM data into PostGIS database. Perhaps this answer about the next steps is still valid https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256111/geoserver-osm-windows-sld-styling.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, you cannot use OSM in Geoserver, you need to convert your data to other formats supported by Geoserver. The list of formats is available [here](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/importer/formats.html).

[image]

There is a similar thread [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77700/how-to-publish-openstreetmap-osm-layer-on-geoserver-directly) that explains that it is not possible.